# Double use of em.persist() not working problem

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to use persist for insert data. First `em.persist()` and second `em.persist()` worked very well, but third `em.persist()` didn't work.

I think second `em` and third `em` are sharing same `QuotaProductInfo` VO, so it is not working. I'm not sure my guessing is right.

Anyway, how can I make second and third `em.persist()` both working.

```java
QuotaInfo quotaInfo = new QuotaInfo();      
quotaInfo.setProject(project);
quotaInfo.setSchool(school);
quotaInfo.setRegion(region);                
quotaInfo.setSalesMan(salesMan);
quotaInfo.setStat(stat);
quotaInfo.setRegDate(LocalDateTime.now());
em.persist(quotaInfo);  //here em.persist() 1   

Long maxSeq_ = (Long) em.createQuery("select count(m) from QuotaInfo AS m").getSingleResult();
int maxSeq = maxSeq_.intValue() + 1;

QuotaProductInfo quotaPInfo_1 = new QuotaProductInfo();     
quotaPInfo_1.setName(product1);
quotaPInfo_1.setQnt(qnt1);
quotaPInfo_1.setPriceUnit(0);
quotaPInfo_1.setQuotaSeq(maxSeq);
em.persist(quotaPInfo_1);   //here em.persist() 2               
if(product2!=null) {
    QuotaProductInfo quotaPInfo_2 = new QuotaProductInfo();     
    quotaPInfo_2.setName(product2);
    qnt2 = Integer.parseInt(qnt2_);
    quotaPInfo_2.setQnt(qnt2);
    quotaPInfo_2.setPriceUnit(0);
    quotaPInfo_2.setQuotaSeq(maxSeq);
    em.persist(quotaPInfo_2);   //here em.persist() 3
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: please share your error logs or explain it with more details.

Comment: javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [com.app.uclasserp.vo.QuotaInfo#0]

Comment: Please share the `QuotaProductInfo` entity. The problem is likely the combination of setting and mapping of the id property.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem to change your entity vo class.

```
public class QuotaInfo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int seq;
```

Simply add @GeneratedValue annotaion you can fix the problem.